# How to tell which logic is specified by an arbitrary collection of natural deduction-style rules?

Tags: logic

How to tell which logic is specified by an arbitrary collection of natural deduction-style rules?

Because all the rules given below are tautologies when interpreted as classical logic, I know that the below system doesn't collapse intro trivialism.

I'm also *pretty sure but not 100% positive* that all the rules are consistent when interpreted as intuitionistic logic too.

These rules all come from rules I've seen before for intuitionistic logic, but with a few changes here and there to make sure that all the premises really are necessary. [Here](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/%7Ecse541/15chapter12.pdf) is a handout that shows a proof system for intuitionistic logic with left and right rules and sequents with exactly one conclusion on the right.

---

I'm trying to come up with a collection of rules in a natural-deduction-like calculus that is a proof system for *some variant* of relevant logic as a way of studying relevant logic.

Let $\vdash$ be a two-place relation relating a set of premises to a single conclusion.

In $\Gamma \vdash a $, the right hand side $a$ is a well-formed formula and $\Gamma$ is a set of well-formed formulas.

I'm starting off with three theorems about $\vdash$ that I hope capture some of the *essence of relevantness* and using that to determine whether the rules I'm picking make sense.

- The logic is not contra-classical, i.e. if $\Gamma \vdash a$ holds, then $\lnot\Gamma_1 \lor \lnot \Gamma_2 \lor \cdots \lor a$ is a classical tautology.
- If $\Gamma \vdash c$ and $\Delta \vdash c$ and $\Gamma \subset \Delta$, then $\Gamma = \Delta$.
- Ex falso quodlibet does not hold.

---

Let $F$ be a designated false proposition.

$$ \frac{\Gamma, a \vdash F}{\Gamma \vdash \lnot a} \;\; \text{is right negation intro} $$

$$ \frac{\Gamma \vdash a}{\Gamma, \lnot a \vdash F} \;\; \text{is left negation intro} $$

$$ \frac{\Gamma, a \vdash b}{\Gamma \vdash a \to b} \;\; \text{is right implication intro} $$

Left implication intro *fits the theorems we started out with* because everything in $\Gamma$ is needed to get you an $a$, and everything in $\Delta$ as well as $b$ is needed to get you $c$, the conclusion.

$$ \frac{\Gamma \vdash a \;\;\text{and}\;\; \Delta, b \vdash c}{\Gamma \cup \Delta, a \to b \vdash c} \;\;\text{is left implication intro} $$

There are three distinct left introduction rules for $\text{and}$ because $a \land b$ is a single premise. It's permissible to use the left conjunct or the right conjunct or both, but it is not permissible to use neither. Using neither would make the expression an unnecessary premise.

$$ \frac{\Gamma, a, b \vdash c}{\Gamma, a \land b \vdash c} \;\; \text{is left conjunction introduction} $$

$$ \frac{\Gamma, a \vdash c}{\Gamma, a \land b \vdash c} \;\; \text{is left conjunction introduction} $$

$$ \frac{\Gamma, b \vdash c}{\Gamma, a \land b \vdash c} \;\; \text{is left conjunction introduction} $$

And finally for the inference rules, the right conjunction introduction rule. This rule is harder to apply than the equivalent rule in classical or intuitionistic logic because we have to be careful how we split the premises between the left and the right sequents.

$$ \frac{\Gamma \vdash a \;\;\text{and}\;\; \Delta \vdash b}{\Gamma, \Delta \vdash a \land b} $$

Let the following be an axiom.

$$ a \vdash a \;\; \text{is the axiom of identity} $$

Comment: You might want to have a look at [substructural logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-substructural/), in particular systems like $FL_{e}$ (called _Full Lambek Calculus with Exchange_).

Comment: Your system does not quite do the trick because you have $a,b\vdash a\land b$ and $a\land b\vdash a$. Now assuming that you also want to have some form of the cut rule, you get $a,b\vdash a$, violating your second theorem about $\vdash$.